# Interacting with hidden fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I'm adding fragments to my activity in way that I first hide current fragment and then add new one. My problem is that when I show my new fragment and start interacting with him, it also interacts with previous one.

The code which I use to add new and hide current fragment is:

```
public void add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(currentFragment).add(containerViewId, fragment);
    if (addToBackStack){
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    ft.commit();
    currentFragment = fragment;
    backStackCount++;
}
```

What is going on, and how to hide fragment so I can interact only with the last one added? `replace` is not an option because I don't want to remove current fragment.

Answer (score 2):

I also had similar problem. I don't know what possibly is creating this issue but what I did to resolve it is that I set an onclick listener to the outermost layout of my fragment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/top_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:clickable="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Fragments.TopicsFragment">

...other components
</LinearLayout>
```

In fragment:

```
LinearLayout topLayout = (LinearLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
topLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do nothing 
        }
    });
```

Also you might see I have added a background #FFFFFF to this outermost layout, because in mycase the content of previous fragment was also visible behind the new one. So this solved that problem too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried this and it works, but this seems 'hackish'. I am looking for the reason why this is happening, too.